# Azure API App anonymous users and authentication

Tags: authentication, azure

After looking through multiple tutorials and posts, I have not found an answer or guide as to how to handle the following issue:

1. There is an Azure API App communicating with an Azure DocumentDB
2. There will be an Azure Web App (and some day mobile apps) communicating with the API App.
3. I would like for anonymous users to have access to read only information through the Web App (and only through the Web App). The
      API App will serve up documents as requested. Anonymous users
      connecting directly to the API App should not be allowed to retrieve
      any information.
4. For contributors, they will be able to add documents using the Web App
          when they are logged in. The documents will go through the API App
          to be written to the DocumentDB

What are the suggested ways for handling anonymous users and authenticated users so both can use the Web App and the underlying API App successfully while blocking any use of the API App if it does not come from the Web App (or future mobile apps)? I only want anonymous users to be able to retrieve information when using the Web App.

The API App is developed in C# .NET 4.5, and the Web App will be the same. I'm not planning on writing my own authentication since the Azure Gateway takes care of this, but it only has the options of Public (Anonymous), Public (Authenticated), and Internal. Public (Anonymous) lets everyone in, while Public (Authenticated) blocks the anonymous users that I would like to have read only access. I'm very new to dealing with Authentication so I'm not even sure if this is possible without having to write my own authentication engine.

For clarification, this question is purely for Authentication between the Web App and the API App.

Thanks,

Comment: This question is way too broad as it is currently written.  You haven't mentioned the technology that the API App is developed in, but authentication would be the responsibility of that API App, not Azure.  Authentication is a VERY broad subject, and most API frameworks have full stack Authentication providers available;  If you intend to write your own authentication engine, it will be much easier for others to help you if you narrow your focus to a specific challenge you are facing (with code), rather than an entire domain concept.

Comment: I think you might still be missing a key concept here.  Azure application gateway is meant for application wide access control, it is not an authorization service.  Authentication and authorization are two different but complimentary concepts.

Comment: That probably is the problem that I am getting things mixed up. I would like to authenticate that only my web app can access the api app, and then I will authorize what can be accessed based on whether or not the user is anonymous or not. I'll use attributes for authorization, but would like to know how to prevent anything but my web app from accessing the api app.